# Free tool to gather daily per-url stats from nginx access log

Tags: linux, nginx, logging

I need to analyze nginx access logs, and come up with stats in this format (or equivalent):

```
DD-MM-YYYY /url hits-total hits-unique
```

Where unique hits are determined per-ip.

All log analysis solutions that I've checked out collect these stats with monthly granularity.

Is there a free tool, which allows to gather the stats I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better served by a custom python, perl or even bash script to analyze those logs and extract those statistics for you, since you want hits per url per day.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. But it is strange — is this request so exotic?

Comment: I am trying to find a way to justify it's *exoticness*  but I can't think of anything. The only really specific thing on your request is the statistic to be by URL, and not by domain as normally is done. Also, most people is more concerned about request per second that is measured differently.

Comment: Well, Google Analytics does what I need (but I can't use it, because I need to analyze logs and can't add JS code on page). This means that the request is not *that* exotic. So can't really get it why log analysis tools don't do that... Oh, well..